# XML Schema: what is the benefit of a restriction based on xs:anyType

Tags: jakarta-ee, xsd, wsdl

In a project we have to connect to a webservice which in its wsdl defines lots of types that restrict based on xs:anyType like this:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="myElement" type="myTypeDef" />

    <xs:complexType name="myTypeDef">
          <xs:complexContent>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                  <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="elementOne" type="xs:string"/>
                      <xs:element name="elementTwo" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
              </xs:restriction>
          </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

What is the difference to a plain type definition like

```
    <xs:complexType name="myTypeDefPlain">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elementOne" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="elementTwo" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

As far as I understand both type definitions are identical. Is that true? Is there any usecase for using a restriction based on xs:anyType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, none. Check [the spec, §3.4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type), particularly the example:

> ```
> <xs:complexType name="length2">
>  <xs:complexContent>
>   <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
>    <xs:sequence>
>     <xs:element name="size" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
>     <xs:element name="unit" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
>    </xs:sequence>
>   </xs:restriction>
>  </xs:complexContent>
> </xs:complexType>
>
> <xs:complexType name="length3">
>  <xs:sequence>
>   <xs:element name="size" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
>   <xs:element name="unit" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
>  </xs:sequence>
> </xs:complexType>
> ```
>
> length3 is the abbreviated alternative to length2: **they correspond to
>   identical type definition components**.